# Getting profiling file from "stack exec"

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I would like to profile a program that is being managed by Stack. The file was built using with the following command:

`stack build --executable-profiling --library-profiling --ghc-options="-fprof-auto -rtsopts"`

And run with this command

`stack exec myProgram.exe -- inputArg +RTS -p`

I know that the program has run (from the output file) but I am expecting a `myProgram.prof` file to be produced as well, I cannot find this file.

If I execute the program without using stack the profiling file is produced, but is there a way to get this to work using Stack?

Comment: When I do this with a blank project (`stack new foo`), I _do_ get a .prof. From your `.exe`, I'm guessing you're on Windows? What's your `stack --version`? (You might also get better help by filing a issue on Stack's GitHub.)

Comment: My version is 1.0.4. Yes I am running on Windows.

Comment: I'm running 1.0.4 on Mac OS and it works fine, perhaps it is a bug on the windows' stack implementation.

Comment: I reproduced this on Windows 7. It's only for RTS options, -ddump options still will produce the dumps in `./stack-work/dist/`.

Comment: https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/2022

Answer (score 0):

`--` stops the RTS from processing further command-line arguments but is passed through to the program. So, your `--` is visible to both `stack` and `myProgram.exe` and therefore the `+RTS -p` flags are not visible to `myProgram.exe`'s RTS. Instead try

```
stack exec -- myProgram.exe inputArg +RTS -p
```